# Does tidal heating imply orbit degradation?

Tags: orbit, planet, tidal-forces

What compensate the energy loss in tidal heating? Is it orbital decay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a wonderful [post](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/9290/why-does-the-moon-drift-away-from-earth) at Physics Stackexchange:

> Gravitational coupling between the Moon and the tidal bulge nearest the Moon acts as a torque on the Earth's rotation, draining angular momentum and rotational kinetic energy from the Earth's spin. In turn, angular momentum is added to the Moon's orbit, accelerating it, which lifts the Moon into a higher orbit with a longer period. As a result, the distance between the Earth and Moon is increasing, and the Earth's spin slowing down.

You can find more reading material and information in the original thread.